# How to get auto response value by using Two Drop-Down List in PHP & Ajax?

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, dropdown, php-7

How to get the final value in AJAX using two drop-down value,

Koluextension.php

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title> Upgrade Cost</title>
  </head>

<form method='POST' action='upgradecost.php'>

Name            : <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
Email Id        : <input type="text" name="email_id"/><br/><br/>
Contact Number  : <input type="text" name="contact_number"/><br/><br/>
I have          :
<select onchange="getvalue()" id="old">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select><br/><br/>
I want          :
<select onchange="getvalue()" id="new">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

upgratedcost.php

```
   <?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];
    if($old=='one'&&$new=='two'){
        echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'10$'));
        }
        else{echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'0'));}
} ?>
```

calculatecost.php

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];
    if($old=='one'&&$new=='two'){
        echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'10$'));
        }
        else{echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'0'));}
} ?>
```

Expected Output:

[image]

> If customer choose: I have -> **one** and I want -> **two** the cost should
>   be **$10** as an **Auto response to show to the customer**. [Every combination has its own cost]

Comment: Where's your ajax call? You can use [jQuery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with the two selected values as parameters in order to call a php page that gives you the result

Answer (score 2):

I have done some changes to your code. And add some Ajax to this and also created separate PHP code, you can get basic idea using this code example.

Html page -

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Upgrade Cost</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form method='POST' action='upgradecost.php'>

Name            : <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
Email Id        : <input type="text" name="email_id"/><br/><br/>
Contact Number  : <input type="text" name="contact_number"/><br/><br/>
I have          :
<select id="old">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select><br/><br/>
I want          :
<select id="new">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select>
</form>
<button id="btn_check_value">Check for value</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_check_value').on('click',function(){
            var old_val = $("#old option:selected").val();
            var new_val = $("#new option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "value_calculate.php",
                data: { old: old_val, new: new_val }
              })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
        })
    })

    </script>
</html>
```

PHP page code -

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];
    if($old=='one'&&$new=='two'){echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'10$'));}else{echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'0'));}
} ?>
```

Here what happen is, once user do the selections user have to click the "Check for value" button and once user click on that button it'll make Ajax request to PHP page "value_calculate.php" and php code return value according to user selection.

This is not complete solution but you can get basic idea and improve this code according to you.

Thanks,
Tharanga.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:
1) Modify Your HTML like this:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title> Upgrade Cost</title>
  </head>

<form method='POST' action='upgradecost.php'>

Name            : <input type="text" name="name"/><br/><br/>
Email Id        : <input type="text" name="email_id"/><br/><br/>
Contact Number  : <input type="text" name="contact_number"/><br/><br/>
I have          :
<select onchange="getvalue()" id="old">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select><br/><br/>
I want          :
<select onchange="getvalue()" id="new">
<option value = "select_option">Select Option</option>
<option value = "one">One</option>
<option value = "two">Two</option>
<option value = "three">Three</option>
<option value = "four">Four</option>
<option value = "five">Five</option>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

2) Add this JavaScript function to your page:

```
function getValue() {
var cost1=$('#old').val();
var cost2=$('#new').val();

 $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url("calculateCost.php") }}',
        type: 'get',
        //async:true,
        data: {
            oldId: cost1,
            NewId: cost2,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
           //you can calculate total cost on server and show updated cost using 
           //jquery anywhere on your form
          //do whatever you wanted to do
        //you can easily manipulate DOM using jQuery
  },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            //in case ajax call error
        }
    });
    }
  }
 }
```

Haven't tested this code. Please make necessary changes. If you still don't know what is going on then I would recommend you to go through a detailed tutorial in order to understand the concepts first and then code. e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: You can create a file calculateCost.php and use this as indicated by @Sri :

<?php

if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];
    if($old=='one'&&$new=='two'){echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'10$'));}else{echo json_encode(array('sucess'=>'sucess','msg'=>'0'));}
} ?>

Answer (score 0):

**Issues** (based from your post in daniweb website):

- There is no input field with an id of `est_shi_val`
- Looking at your code, you want to use both the `old` and `new` select fields, when changed will put the result to a hidden input field. But the result will only return if both the `old` and `new` have selected options. Is this what you want? Or at least one of them should be selected, and the result will return?
- Use a database to look-up for conditions instead of manually creating `if-else` conditions

**Instructions:**
You may remove first your `onchange` attribute/call in your `old` and `new` select fields.

**AJAX Call:**

```
$("#old, #new").change(function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE OLD OR NEW INPUT FIELD */
  var old = $("#old").val(),
      newval = $("#new").val();

  $.ajax({ /* TRIGGER THE AJAX CALL */
    type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
    url: "ajax_ship_data.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
    data: {'old':old, 'new':newval}, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){ /* GET THE RETURNED DATA */
      $("#results").html(result.message); /* THE RETURNED MESSAGE WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV, PROVIDED THAT YOU HAVE A DIV WITH AN ID OF "results" */
      $('#shipping_weight').val(result.weight); /* ASSUMING THAT YOU HAVE A HIDDEN INPUT FIELD WITH AN ID OF "shipping_weight" */
    }
  });

});
```

Then at your `ajax_ship_data.php`:

```
$shipping_weight = 0;
$message = 'Please select an option from both fields.';

if(isset($_POST['old']) && isset($_POST['new'])){
    $old = $_POST['old'];
    $new = $_POST['new'];

    //part 1 
    if($old == 'three_compact' && $new == 'five_compact'){
        $shipping_weight = 10;
        $message = 'Shipping weight is 10.';
    }
    /** REST OF IF-ELSE CONDITIONS **/
}

echo json_encode(array('message' => $message, 'weight' => $shipping_weight));
```

**Other Option: No AJAX**

You may also do this without using AJAX since you're manually creating conditions:

```
$("#old, #new").change(function(){
    var old = $("#old").val(),
        newval = $("#new").val();

    if(old=='three_compact' && newval=='five_compact'){
        $("#results").text('10');
    }
    /* REST OF IF-ELSE CONDITIONS */
});
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6svg8fhx/).

Comment: May i know how to solve the error: https://snag.gy/WMT1mK.jpg @Logan Wayne

Comment: @Gem remove the hovered tool-tip so I could see the declared variable before the error. I'm assuming that you add `var` again in declaring the `new` variable.

Comment: @Gem - forgot that `new` is a reserved word. You may change it to `newval` instead. Look at my updated answer.